# Why cacerts update is needed in Kubernetes

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

When reading files from a Google Storage Bucket from within a container running in GKE or GCE. The following code fails:

```
public String readSmallTextFileFromBucket(String bucketName, String textFile) {

        Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName, textFile);
        String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
        return fileContent;
        }
```

With the error:

```
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

If I replace the default `java/jdk-10.0.2/lib/security/cacerts` file you get when you download OpenJDK with the one from my desktop, the code above works.

Why is that? and what is the correct way to enable the Java API to read from a storage bucket from within a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by changing 2 things.
a) Adding storage-rw to the cluster scopes and
b) There was a mistake with how I was creating my kubernetes secret

No idea how or why replacing cacerts file helped, but the above 2 fixes are the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Many base container images by default may not include the CA Certificates that's normally installed on every computer. (Because not everyone needs to use TLS in a container.) You often need to "apt-get install" or similar in your Dockerfile to install these certificates.

Without CA certificates present in a container, your code can't trust storage.googleapis.com.

See the commands required to add CA certificates to your container in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/633853/35769 Ideally you shouldn't copy these certs from your desktop machine.

Comment: My docker file is built FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-rc2-gpu I added    
 RUN apt-get install ca-certificates \
 && update-ca-certificates    
But the same error occured. The output from gcloud builds submit indicated that the latest certs are already installed.

Comment: Fair point, I'm not familiar with how Java does this. But beware that this works for most people using Docker. Maybe open an issue to Tensorflow's dockerfile repository. Also the issue is probably not GCE/GKE only, are you able to query https websites in your Java code?