# Mount Security Certificate into Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine so Java Apps can find valid cert path

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google's Kubernetes Engine to deploy a few Spring Boot apps. I have set ingress up with HTTPS which is working great, but when one of the apps tries to access my authorization server, which is on HTTPS, Java gives me the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException
```

**I know how to fix this locally, but how do I fix this so my Java apps deployed on GKE are able find the valid `.cer` file?**

I tried including the `.cer` file directly on the Docker image from my Dockerfile, but that is not really intuitive if my certificates expire and was unable to get it work.

I currently have the crt file and key file mounted as a secret, and the ingress is using it just fine. Previously, I was using Google Cloud's self managed certificate which worked perfectly as well, but I wanted to test using Kubernetes secrets.
`

I figure the best option is to mount the `.cer` onto my cluster and point the deployments to use it through environment variables. That way I can easily update when they expire, and I won't have to redeploy each image.

**Update:**

I mounted the keystore.jks as a secret volume onto my deployment.yaml and configured Spring Boot to look at that path, but it was to no avail.

Spring Boot Properties

```yaml
server.ssl.key-store: /mnt/secret/keystore.jks
# other configuration removed for SSL
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but when one of the apps tries to access my authorization server" .
How apps accessing auth server? through ingress and FQDN or as kubernetes service name?

Comment: @cela Was the information that I posted in my answer, useful for you? Or, can I help you with other information?

Comment: @NestorDanielOrtegaPerez Hello Nestor, I haven't had a chance to test anything yet. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: @VladUlshin My authorization server is on the same Ingress as the Spring Boot apps. The  Spring Boot apps use the Ingress and FQDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue in **GCP’s GKE**, sometimes replacing cacerts files helps to solve it, but following these steps is the correct way to do it:

a) Use a **Service Account**. In order to have more reference about the **GCP’s Service Accounts**, take a look into this [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#serviceaccount).

b) Add `storage-rw` scope to the cluster’s scopes when creating the cluster. As this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create) indicates, you can do it with the command:

```
gcloud container clusters create example-cluster --scopes=bigquery,storage-rw,compute-ro
```

Use this [GCP GKE’s official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) for more reference regarding to the **GCP’s IAM Access Scopes**.

c) Review in detail how you are creating your **Kubernetes Secret**. For more guidance, use this [Official GKE’s Secrets Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret).

Plus, you can use these threads as a reference too [Why is cacerts update needed in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094694/why-cacerts-update-is-needed-in-kubernetes/53357568#53357568), [How to Fix javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException](https://www.java67.com/2019/06/javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception-PKIX-path-building-failed-ssl-certificate.html) and [KubernetesAPIJavaClient](https://github.com/nirmal070125/KubernetesAPIJavaClient).